# mod_rewrite to page with HTTP auth

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use modrewrite to proxy  http://myserver/cam1 to an internal, http-auth protected server at http://admin:admin@192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi

No matter what I try, though, requests to http://myserver/cam1 always prompt me for the username and password.  I've tried all of these to no avail.

```
RewriteRule ^/cam1 http://admin:admin@192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/cam1 http://192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi [E=Authorization:Basic\ YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/cam1 http://192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi [E=HTTP_USERID:admin,E=HTTP_PASSWORD:admin,P,L]`
```

Anybody have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ^ and /:

```
RewriteRule cam1 http://admin:admin@192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi [P,L]
RewriteRule cam1 http://192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi [E=Authorization:Basic\ YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=,P,L]
RewriteRule cam1 http://192.168.99.130/cgi/mjpg/mjpg.cgi [E=HTTP_USERID:admin,E=HTTP_PASSWORD:admin,P,L]
```

Please tell me if it works.